# default wikipedia.org gadget settings

Tags: wikipedia

**Wikipedia.org only has a toggle for `"Restore all default settings (in all sections)"` meaning not just gadgets.** Equivalent of killing my full account settings to tie my tie exactly. I know technology asks a lot, but maybe you can spare me the ordeal of troubleshooting Wikipedia.org so I can focus again.

Please do not suggest MediaWiki.org defaults, our question is specific to Wikipedia.org's feature-set alone.

Can somebody copy/paste their default https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Preferences "Gadgets" tab/section checkbox settings? Otherwise if I can get some encouragement to open a second account for testing purposes, I have never done that before and could then answer the question myself (and feel like a "karma ****" ...I do not mind being but the asterisked judgement is another story), however I do/did not ever go beyond a second account except for reddit.com, leaves too many questions (telling somebody is then security).

(Question title written as Broken English programmer code like stackexchange.com suggests at the top of my feed, I have heard that called computerese. If I try to talk with my voice there are other questions, so UNIX style.)

Comment: "Otherwise if I can get some encouragement to open a second account for testing purposes, I have never done that before and could then answer the question myself, however I do/did not ever go beyond a second account except for reddit.com, leaves too many questions (telling somebody for the record is then security)." maybe should be a comment.

Comment: I meant to say "beyond a single account", not "beyond a second account"*, the English language can be rough for even the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check at [Special:Gadgets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Gadgets) - the default ones will have "Enabled for everyone by default".
(Or you can just register a new account in an incognito window. It takes about five clicks, not even an email address needed.)

Comment: Thank you for the Special:Gadgets ref. Thank G-d it has the Defaults scored, not always expected behavior (even if should seem obvious to any programmer/developer it does not happen enough).

Comment: °Also, I do not know if you should edit/censor the word "Incognito" might be suspicious and scare, I just read ~~https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Sock_puppetry~~ because of your encouragement (often people openly encourage that behavior (I do not blame you quite for that behavior suggesting "Google Chrome Incognito" stealth/Tor mode, which *you* yourself definitely did not advertise the technique as Good, given we're told to Tor)), & wish there were open source specified standards (or for a change, adults who would admit to having additional accounts for the record) for legitimate uses.

Comment: Maybe "Google Incognito" is the problem, please remove that part and I can vote.